# Convert Ruby on Rails 5 datetime into milliseconds respecting the timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

i am trying to convert a rails datetime into milliseconds but the moment i call `.strftime` or `.to_i` it ignores the timezone assigned to it and reads the system's timezone

```
system timezone: Europe/London # currently is +01:00 due to BST
```

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Europe/Athens' # +03:00
```

```
stored in database as GMT: 2019-04-19 10:00:00.000000

start_date: schedule.start_date,
to_datetime: schedule.start_date.to_datetime,
strftime: schedule.start_date.to_datetime.strftime('%Q').to_i,
```

```
start_date: "2019-04-19T13:00:00.000+03:00",
to_datetime: "2019-04-19T13:00:00.000+03:00",
strftime: 1555668000000, # 2019-04-19T11:00:00.000+01:00
```

it is rendered correctly in the view

```
<%= schedule.start_date %>
# 13:00:00 19 Apr 2019
```

```
irb(main):004:0> Time.at(1555668000)
=> 2019-04-19 11:00:00 +0100
```

i apologize if this has been answered before but i just couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Why do you think that `1555668000` is equal to `2019-04-19T13:00:00.000+01:00`? You are wrong. `1555668000` is equal to `GMT: 2019-04-19 10:00` which in your case is correct and expected.

Comment: Timestamp by definition is is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: You can use Ruby method `Time.at(1555668000)` or any online service found on the internet by the key words `convert unix to utc` to make sure that the result you have is correct

Comment: i want to convert the datetime to milliseconds plus the timezone offset

Comment: According to `1555668000`, if I use `Time.at(1555668000)` I will get `2019-04-19 17:00:00 +0700` which is the time in my local time zone (Bangkok), and that is why you get `2019-04-19 11:00:00 +0100` for your local time zone.

if your expected result is `2019-04-19 13:00:00 +0300`, you may use `Time.zone.at(1555668000).to_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up doing something like this

```
system timezone: UTC
```

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

i then implemented a timezone switcher similar to this 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

```
dst = Time.zone.now.dst?
offset = Time.zone.utc_offset
offset += 3600 if dst

ts = (schedule.start_date.to_i + offset) * 1000
```